# Go server images directory structure for uploads and download

Tags: api, rest, go

I am new to Go and try to build my local server first. In gopath-src directory I have my Server folder[image: with such structure. Folder "test" keeps image files]

I upload data to local database and save uploaded images in their own folder "test".
I use Gin framework and created the route to download images from the server:

```
image := r.Group("/img/anime")
image.GET("/:path", h.GetImage)
```

Now I can access files using Uri:

```
 Glide
.load("http://192.168.1.101:3000/img/anime/image.png")
```

The problem is that this URL has nothing to do with folders on my server, that is if I try to use some extra path, not only a file name, it returns 404 error - file not found(((

It works if images are saved in server root, where go.sum, go.mode and go.main reside.
For folder "test" I used such workaround -

```
func (h handler) GetImage(c *gin.Context) { 
 
 filePath := c.Param("path")  // read 'path'
 dir, file := filepath.Split(filePath)
 
  target := filepath.Join(dir, "test/")  // hardcoded joined 'test/'
  targetPath := filepath.Join(target, file) // then join the file name
 
    c.Header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")  
    c.Header("Content-Type", "image/png") //"application/octet-stream")
    
  c.File(targetPath)  //c.FileAttachment(dir, file)
```

Now it works.. But what if I want to use different sub-directories for files? How to access them dynamically? It is not possible to hardcode all of them.

Instead of image name: *"http://192.168.1.101:3000/img/anime/ -> image.png"*

I would like to use an arbitrary local path+image name in Uri:

*"http://192.168.1.101:3000/img/anime/ -> uploads/1/path/image.png"*

Is it possible?
Actually, if I gonna keep many small image files I need many folders, right? Because accessing one folder containing over 10000 files is slow and may freeze the system..
Also, what is difference between GIN **c.File** and **c.FileAttachment** methods?